# C# - Events for simple class

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I'm struggling to understand how events works on C#. **By now, I'm testing *only* in console applications**. I've tried sometimes by what I read in the MSDN documentation, but unsuccessfully.

Here's is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Events
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TodoList list = new TodoList();
            TodoItem fooItem = new TodoItem
            {
                Title = "FooItemTitle",
                Description = "FooItemDescription",
            };

            TodoItem barItem = new TodoItem
            {
                Title = "BarItemTitle",
                Description = "BarItemDescription",
            };

            // I want to trigger an event everytime a item is added on the
            // TodoList.
            // How can I do that?
            list.AddItem(fooItem);
            list.AddItem(barItem);
        }
    }

    class TodoList
    {
        List<TodoItem> items;
        public TodoList()
        {
            this.items = new List<TodoItem>();
        }

        public void AddItem(TodoItem item)
        {
            this.items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    class TodoItem
    {
        public String Description;
        public String Title;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("[TodoItem]: Title={0} | Description={1}", this.Title, this.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

How would I configure an event to be triggered everytime a `TodoItem` is added on a `TodoList`?

Comment: You can use an `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`, this will create the events for you

Comment: Thanks Eric, I will take a look. But my intent is to understand the Events flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event to `ToDoList`:

```
// note how we assigned a blank delegate to it 
// this is to avoid NullReferenceException when we fire event with no subscribers

public event EventHandler<TodoItem> ItemAdded = (s, e) => { };
```

And trigger it inside of Add method:

```
ItemAdded(this, item);
```

Also don't forget to subscribe to event from some other class:

```
// as eventhandler you should use method that accepts exactly the same 
// number and type of parameters as in delegate EventHandler<TodoItem>  

list.ItemAdded += (eventhandler);
```

Comment: Turns out that my mistake was forgetting to call the Event on my `AddItem` method... Thank you.